# Having terrible lag on a certain server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

As of today, on a certain server I play on, I lag when I get onto the server. I'm able to break blocks and move, but not able to interact with the world. By this I mean that I won't receive blocks I have broken, I cannot use redstone devices, etc. Nor can I chat (so to speak, anyways). Through dynamap, I was able to figure out that others were able to see my chat, however I was not able to see mine or theirs in-game. Sometimes, minutes later, all the actions I performed (chat, block breaking/placing, world interaction), will all come through at once. This will just happen over and over again until I usually get a  "Read time out" error which is odd, since these errors only last for about 2-3 minutes for me, when they occur. (And this has been happening continuously, all day)

NOTE: This only happens for this specific server. All other servers have been acting generally normal, no issues like this. Even the ones that I have ridiculously high ping with (like 2400ms...) are acting normal.

Later, I checked the ping for the server, and it was generally normal, being at its average 240ms or so. I restarted my computer as well, and it still happened. I ran speedtest.net, as well, and received normal results (4.5MPBS upload, 19ishMBPS download).

Is this a problem with my .minecraft? Should I delete it and start fresh? Or is the just a computer/network problem? All help is appreciated.

Comment: i also usffer that a lot

Comment: I think the server is hosted far away and because of that you have high ping and game can't synchronise with the servers logic... There is nothing you can do about it. This is my opinion.

Comment: @Roberts The ping isn't that high, well for me anyways. A lot of my servers are around the 250ms range, and function perfectly fine, this turned out to be a weird occurrence all the sudden. Plus, with my high ping servers, I usually have different lag problems associated with them, nothing is like this. Anyways, the problem has seemed to fix itself. I got on today and it worked perfectly fine. Perhaps my computer just needed a rest...

Comment: Ping-with-just-one-number is just as average. A real ping number has three parts, with min/avg/max. If 250ms is average and min/max are close to 250ms, you'll get smooth connectivity. If 250ms is average but min is very low and max is very high, you'll get severe lag and disconnects, even though your "ping" seems the same.

Comment: To find your actual ping, open a console window (cmd.exe on Windows) and use the `ping <IP address or hostname>` command, using the MC server's IP or name. Then tell us the min/avg/max.

Comment: This has only happened once, and I really have no ways to see if any of these tips explained why it happened, considering it fixed itself. Should I close this question, or just leave it with no accepted answer?

Comment: Definitely sounds like server lag.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could be causing this:

- Proxys, if you're using a proxy it could delay some information and not others.
- Magic Launcher, I have found that having Magic Launcher's console open will stop all incoming connections when it receives a Coloured message. this can be fixed by launching it without the console.
- Distance, if the server you play on is physically further away, then it could severly delay information going between you and the server, especially if you have a slow internet connection, to find where the server is located go to http://geoip.flagfox.net/, type the server IP or domain name in the field that looks like this: [image]
- Server lag, if the server's TPS(Ticks Per Second) is reduced, then it will start giving up on those with a slower connection. this can be fixed by getting a better internet provider.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the comments, this problem 'fixed itself'. this show you just had a temporarily **poor inbound connection**, the factors that can cause this are usually out of your control, such as peak traffic in your local area or local transfer point or excessive.

the problem with not being able to see blocks dropping and stuff like that is when the you (the client) breaks the block so they dissapear, then the server has to verify that you broke them and send you (client) the information about what items should be around that area now that you broke the block